# How Should I Handle Multiple Locations for a Library Project in Android?

Tags: android, ant, adt, library-project, aide-ide

I'm developing an [open source Android app](https://github.com/treborrude/prayerminder). I'd like to use multiple development platforms. The first is my [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/) box, where I use `ant` and `emacs` for development (because I've used `emacs` for years and Gentoo currently lacks support for a version of Eclipse new enough to support ADT). The other is [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui) on my Android tablet.

The main problem I'm having at the moment is related to my use of [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) as a library project. Naturally, the location of the library project is different on the Gentoo box and on the tablet. And if anyone ever clones the repository, I'd like to make it as easy as possible for them to get things set up.

Now, it seems to me that this is the same sort of problem that is solved by setting `sdk.dir` in the `local.properties` file. So my first thought was to add an `abs.dir=<path to ActionBarSherlock>` setting in `local.properties` which I then reference in `project.properties`. Doing that works fine with `ant` on the Gentoo box.

However, it doesn't seem to work with AIDE on the tablet. Since `local.properties` is not checked into the git repo, I created a new one on the tablet with `abs.dir` pointed to the tablet location of ActionBarSherlock. But AIDE doesn't seem to be using it (even though it's referenced in the `build.xml` file). I know how to set up AIDE to use the library project, but that modifies `project.properties` (which IS checked into the git repo) to have the full path to the tablet loction of ABS, which is definitely not what I want (I certainly don't want to have to update that file every time I switch between the tablet and the Gentoo box).

So is there a way to set things up to build in both `ant` and Eclipse / AIDE while only needing to modify a single setting between the systems? Or will I need to update my project's README to include a detailed list of instructions about how to set things up?

Comment: As of July 2013, ActionBarSherlock is no longer necessary, since revision 18 of the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) added ActionBar support back to Android 2.1. But the question would still apply to any third party library.

Comment: Did you find the solution for setting locations of libraries in general in project.properties or you think it is better to keep that file out of repo?!

Comment: Sorry @Ewoks, but I haven't found the solution. I haven't really had a lot of time to work on development projects at home.